# Joi doesn't write validation errors to log

Tags: javascript, joi, hapi

I'm using Joi for input validation. I'm good with the error response I have from Joi, but I want to print it to log.
I know the option to handle failures in 'options' part like:

```
options: {
  response: {
    failAction: async (req, h, err) => {
      if(err) {
          console.log(`Server error: ${err}`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But since I have a lot of APIs, I don't want to add an handler for each one of them.
I'm searching for this log coming from Joi framework whenever a validation fails.

Joi version: 17.1.1

Comment: Did you try using [req.log](https://hapi.dev/tutorials/logging/?lang=en_US)?

Comment: This should be done separately for each request/validation.
I'm looking for an error printing by Joi for every failure.

Comment: You can set the failAction once for every request. It is easy if you are using a Glue manifest file. Check out this example: https://github.com/hapijs/glue/issues/113#issuecomment-359217675

Comment: Since I have a lot of APIs I thought maybe it's possible to tell Joi by configuration or some other way to print all the errors to log. This way I can do it in one place.

Comment: Thank you @soltex. Your link was helping me to solve the issue as I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally succeeded by adding the following code in my server.js file:

```
server.events.on('response', function (request) {
        if (request.response !== undefined && request.response.source !== undefined && request.response.source.validation !== undefined &&
            request.response.source.validation.source === "payload") {
            logger.error(request.response.source.validation);
        }
    });
```

If statement is needed to handle only Joi validation errors and not to print all response errors.